# Creating a Google Line Chart from MYSQL data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

My aim is to create multiple line charts on the same graph using data i pull from mysql database.

I have the code in place but I'm missing a step therefore not getting the output I expect. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $results = array('cols' => array (array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => date'),
               array('label' => 'Amount', 'type' => 'number')
               ),
               'rows' => array()
              );

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Claims GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ClaimDate ) , EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ClaimDate ) ');

    $query->execute();
    $rows1 = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($rows1 as $row)
    {
        $ClaimDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['ClaimDate'])->format('Y-m-d');

        $dateArr = explode('-', $ClaimDate);
        $year = (int) $dateArr[0];
        $month = (int) $dateArr[1] - 1; 
        $day = (int) $dateArr[2];

        $results['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day)"), array('v' => $row['amount'])
        ));
    }
    $json = json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    // print_r($json);exit;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() 
{
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($json); ?>);
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
   chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}   
</script>
<div id="line_chart"></div>
```

So that's my code. This is the json that is passed to the chart from the database:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Amount","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 5, 23)"},{"v":6000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016, 5, 23)"},{"v":16000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 6, 23)"},{"v":10000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016, 6, 23)"},{"v":10000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 7, 23)"},{"v":5000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016, 7, 23)"},{"v":60000}]}]}
```

And below is the line chart that is output:

[line chart output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Mn4.png)

This is not what I want. My end goal is to get graph that displays multiple line charts(depending on the number of years present) with all the months displaying on the X-axis with the amount displaying on the Y-axis. This is the closest thing I've seen that resembles what I want to achieve:

[linechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II4gB.png)

The above image shows what I want to achieve. Like stated before, the months on the X-axis with the amount on the Y-axis. then the 'values' would be the years that have been returned from the query i.e. every year will have its own line chart

I'm a bit stuck on this and would like to request for guidance on how to accomplish this

**Additional request**

SIDU has tried to provide assistance by recommending I use the svg charts. Appreciated but can't this be done using google charts?

Comment: try: http://topnew.net/chart/

Comment: ok. will give it a look

Comment: need separate columns for each year -- each column creates a separate line / series -- use `null` for other column values if column year doesn't match row date

Comment: ok. remember it has to be done dynamically

Comment: still need help with this question?

Comment: I'm good WhiteHat. i restructured my question which you brilliantly provided an answer. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy with Topnew SVG Charts:

http://topnew.net/cms/cms_chart.php?data=ymd,Hit,IP;2016-01-01,2000,1000;2016-02-05,3000,1800;2016-03-20,4000,3000&chart=line&fmt=str_xss&xFormat=date|M

If you download the 9k topnew svg chart, you can call it in the following way instead:

```
<?php
include 'topnew_svg_chart.php';
$data = [
    'Hit' => [
        '2016-01-01' => 12345,
        '2016-02-03' => 12345,
    ],
    'IP'  => [
        '2016-01-01' => 2345,
        '2016-02-03' => 2345,
    ]
];
$init = [
    'chart'   => 'line',
    'xFormat' => 'date|M',
];
cms_chart($data, $init);
```

Comment: Hey SIDU. Been loking atthe svg chart. Could you please guide me on how to dynamically populate the chart?